# Dynamically load specific page from other html file

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a situation in jQuery mobile

```
<a class="fa fa-pencil editInfo">Click</a>
```

Inside `updateInfoPages.html` :

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="adminPage">
</div>

<div id="page2" data-role="page" data-theme="a" class="adminPage">
</div>
```

On `.editInfo` click i want to navigate to `page1` or `page2` based on some condition.

1. So how can i navigate to these pages ?
2. How will I know that `page1` or `page2` has been loaded ?

I tried this

```
$(".editInfo").click(function(){
  $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "updateInfoPages.html",{data:{"p1":"p111","p2":"p22"}});
});
```

It only shows `page1` and also if i refresh `updateInfoPages.html` all css style is removed.

Comment: You should either put all your page divs in one file or one per html file. Mixing like this is not the way jQM was designed to work.